# should a UIActionSheet prompt issued during "viewDidLoad" method halt code in the method until it is actioned by user?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiactionsheet

should a UIActionSheet prompt issued during "viewDidLoad" method halt code in the method until it is actioned by user?

Background: I am trying to use UIActionSheet to prompt the user during "viewDidLoad" to ask whether they want test Data populated, however it appears that the rest of the lines of code in the "viewDidLoad" method keep completing whilst the prompt is waiting for user input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split your initializing code into a main initializer and the action sheet delegate method. Call your action sheet from the initializer and let the delegate method finish the initializing there.

Comment: arrr - penny dropped on the 2nd read of your comment DarkDust   :)

Answer (score 1):

you can't wait (= halt your code) for input of an UIActionSheet or anything else.

You have to implement a [UIActionSheetDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIModalViewDelegate_Protocol/UIActionSheetDelegate/UIActionSheetDelegate.html) and do what you want to do inside the `actionSheet:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` method.